# Conditional statement not agreeing with list index in a loop

Tags: r, function

My data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(pop = c("Spades", "Spades", "Spades", "Clubs", "Clubs", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Hearts"),
            type = c("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Ace", "Two", "King", "Queen"),
            V1 = c(4, 3, NA, 7, NA, NA, 5, 12, NA, NA),
            V2 = c(16, 23, NA, 15, NA, NA, 8, 19, NA, NA))
```

I need to impute NA's to 0's, but only in very specific cases. For each pop (population) and type, the data (V1, V2, etc) has to contain either all NA's or all numbers. So in this example, the Spades pop is missing data in V1 and V2 for the Spades-Three row, while Spades-Ace and Spades-Two has data. So V1 and V2 for Spades-Three will need to change from NA to 0. The same will also apply to the Clubs pop.

The resulting dataset should look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(pop = c("Spades", "Spades", "Spades", "Clubs", "Clubs", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Hearts"),
            type = c("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Ace", "Two", "King", "Queen"),
            V1 = c(4, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 12, NA, NA),
            V2 = c(16, 23, 0, 15, 0, 0, 8, 19, NA, NA))
```

I am able to carry out this imputation with this code:

```
ID <- unique(df$pop)  

for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
   dftemp <- filter(df, pop == paste(ID[i]))
   # Number of unique categories for a pop-type combination
   num_type <- length(dftemp$type)
   # Number of NA's in that combination for V1
   num_na <- sum(is.na(dftemp$V1) == TRUE)
   print(num_type)
   print(num_na)
   if (num_na < num_type && num_na > 0) {
     # print(paste(ID[i]))
     df$V1[with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(V1))] <- 0
     df$V2[with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(V2))] <- 0
   }
}
```

My problem is in scaling up. I will need to do this for many more columns, so I want to put the column names into a list that I can then pass through with a loop. But for some reason, in the last `if` loop, changing from

`df$V1[with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(V1))] <- 0`

to

`df[newlist[k]][with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(newlist[k]))] <- 0`

(where `newlist <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")` etc)
makes the `pop == paste(ID[i])` condition no longer work. If I specify `pop == "Spades"`, then it works, but obviously this is even less efficient than the old method.

The ultimate goal is to create a function where I can just pass in the df name and the list of columns to get this to work, but I find myself being bottle-necked by this problem.

My current attempt at writing a function looks something like this:

```
imputezero <- function(df, columnlist) {
  for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
    for (x in 1:length(columnlist)) {
      dftemp <- filter(df, pop == paste(ID[i]))
      num_type <- length(dftemp$type)
      num_na <- sum(is.na(dftemp[collist[x]]) == TRUE)
      if (num_na < num_type && num_na > 0) {
        df[columnlist[x]][with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(df[columnlist[x]]))] <- 0
        return(df)
      }
    }
  }
}

list_status <- c("V1", "V2")
test_df <- imputezero(df, list_status)
```

So how can I get `df[columnlist[x]][with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(df[columnlist[x]]))] <- 0` to work?

I'd also welcome any feedback if my general approach is all wrong or if there's a way to cut out all the noise.

Comment: Try reducing your problem to a minimal reproducible problem. So that we could understand more easily your problem. Plus you might find a solution in the process

Comment: My code snippets are reproducible. I guess the crux of where I'm stuck at is in the middle section, in changing this 

df$V1[with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(V1))] <- 0

to

df[newlist[k]][with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(newlist[k]))] <- 0

I added the other snippets to clarify what the other lists and objects are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the if in your function to skip a loop when num_ra is equal to num_type or num_na is zero. Then I perform the df[columnlist[x]][with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(df[columnlist[x]]))] <- 0 line of code. I moved the return(df) to the end of the function. This seems to work.

```
imputezero <- function(df, columnlist) {
  for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
    for (x in 1:length(columnlist)) {
      dftemp <- filter(df, pop == paste(ID[i]))
      num_type <- length(dftemp$type)
      num_na <- sum(is.na(dftemp[columnlist[x]]) == TRUE)
      if (num_na == num_type | num_na == 0) {
        next
      }
        df[columnlist[x]][with(df, pop == paste(ID[i]) & is.na(df[columnlist[x]]))] <- 0

    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `mutate_at` from `dplyr`, it will scales with any number of columns

If I understood correctly you can do :

```
df %>%
  group_by(pop) %>%
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(ifelse(is.na(.) & sum(is.na(.)) != n(), 0, .)), 
            .vars = vars(-type))
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the other answer for now, but I'll keep this in mind for when I have time to further optimise my code. mutate_at sounds like the right way to go and will hopefully help me to speed up my run time.